# Looking for specific number in regular expression

Tags: regex

I need to find a regular expression in a text that is like this expression:

> -214\d{7}‏

except for this specific number that matches the expression:**-2147444133**

Comment: Are you at all familiar with regular expressions? If not, I suggest that you read up on them and try to find an expression that works, yourself. Also, knowing what language you are implementing this in (python, ruby, java...) will help. If that one number must be excluded, you could also do an if/else statement

Comment: @HunterStevens, I need the it all in an expression with out using if/else.

Comment: Does your program work with an if/else statement? If so, use it and move on to the next part. Worry about an all-powerful regex at the end. Now, if you are at that point, like I said -- review how to use regex in the language you are developing in.

Comment: Please tag this with a programming language or some other way of knowing what dialect of regex you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using PCRE or something else with perl-style negative lookahead assertions, you can use:

```
(?!-2147444133)-214\d{7}
```

If you are unlucky enough to be in an environment without that available, you can go the long route:

```
-214(?:[0-68-9]\d{6}|7[0-35-9]\d{5}|74[0-35-9]\d{4}|744[0-35-9]\d{3}|7444[02-9]\d\d|74441[0-24-9]\d|744413[0-24-9])
```